# Can I add or sort by a MongoDB match object?

Tags: mongodb, sorting

So I have two collections, Trait and Question. For a given user, I iterate over the user's traits, and I want to query all of the questions that correspond to missing traits:

```
linq.From(missingTraits)
.ForEach(function(trait)
{
    match.$or.push({ "Trait": trait });
});

database.collection("Questions", function(err, collection)
{
    collection.find(match).limit(2).toArray(function(err, questions)
    {
        next(err, questions);
    });
});
```

This works, but I'd like the objects to come back sorted by a field on the Trait document  (which is NOT on the Question document):

```
Traits
[
  { "Name": "Height", "Value": "73", "Importance": 15 },
  { "Name": "Weight", "Value": "230" "Importance": 10 },
  { "Name": "Age", "Value": "29", "Importance": 20 }
]

Questions
[
  { "Trait": "Height", "Text": "How tall are you?" },
  { "Trait": "Weight", "Text": "How much do you weight?" },
  { "Trait": "Age", "Text": "How old are you?" }
]
```

So in the above example, if all three traits were missing, I'd want to bring back only Age and height (in that order). Is it possible to modify the query or the match object in some way to facilitate this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question right, you would like to find the two most important traits?  If your `missingTraits` array is just the names of the traits ("Height", "Weight", "Age"), then you would want to query the Traits collection to find the two most important, before sending the query to the Questions collection.

Unfortunately, modifying just the query on your Questions collection will not work without a separate call to the Traits collection, since that is where the information on importance lives.

A query like

```
database.collection("Traits", function(err, collection)
{
    collection.find(match).sort({ Importance : -1 }).limit(2).toArray(function(err, traits)
    {
        // cache the traits to query the questions collection
    });
});
```

will get you the two most important Traits that match the $or query (all matches, sorted by Importance by descending order, limited to 2).  You can then use these results to query the Questions collection.

Telling the Questions collection to return the docs in "Age", "Height" order is difficult in this case, so I would recommend caching the importance order of the traits you receive back from the Traits collection and then sorting the results of the query on Questions client-side.

Here are the docs for `sort()`:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%7B%7Bsort%28%29%7D%7D

One last thing: if you are populating `missingTraits` via a database call to the Traits collection, then it should be possible to place the `sort()` logic into that call, rather than adding a second call to the collection.